# What are current epidemiologic standards for space?

Tags: astronauts, health, standards

In the recent Mars series by National Geographic I've seen that an astronaut dies from a brain tumor because it "was not part of screening".

Now could this be real and what are health standards for space especially regarding infectious deceases i.e. caused by bacteria and viruses? We carry lots of them with us, are we going to put effort into definitely leaving some of them on Earth?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_(2016_TV_series)

Comment: What recent "Mars series"? Books? Television? YouTube? It's a pretty international crowd here.

Comment: Different but related questions tagged with both `astronauts` and `health`: [What are the physical requirements of an astronaut for a Mars mission likely to be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25705/12102) and [Do Astronauts have their appendix removed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30439/12102) and [What psychiatric and psychological tests do people need to pass to become astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33771/12102)